# Shell in garden snail

Tags: molluscs

I was wondering that how does shell of garden snail "grows " with growth of snail. 
Small snail possess shell as its size but as it grows shell grows. How do they enlarge cavity inside shell?

Answer (score 2):

The snails enlarge the shell by adding material at the lip.  The addition of material is sometimes noncontinuous and shows up as rings, sort of like tree rings.  You can see the growth rings in this photo.

[image: snail shells with growth rings]
I found the photo here http://ediblesouthflorida.ediblecommunities.com/things-do/snails-slugs-millipedes-oh-my

As the shell spirals outward the diameter of the added rings gets larger and larger.  It has to get larger if it is to spiral - addition of the same sized rings would make a donut-like torus.